# Proving that a function is increasing

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

I have this problem

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function, such that its Taylor series convergers to function $f$ everywhere. For every derivative of the function $f$ we have that $f^{(n)}(0) \ge 1 \ (n=0,1,2,\cdots).$ I have to show that $f$ is an increasing function on $[0,\infty).$

Thanks for any answers or hints

Comment: **Hint**: What's the Taylor expansion of $f'$ ?

Comment: Do we know the series to be centered at $0$?

Comment: No, there is nothing about the center of the series in the text.

Comment: @gash If any taylor series is globally convergent, so are all. In other words, WLOG the center _is_ $0$.

Answer (score 1):

First we differentiate the $f(x)$ with respect to $x$ using it's Maclaurin series:$$
f'(x) =\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f^{(n)}\frac{x^n}{n!}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{(n)}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
$$We know that both $f^{(n)}\geq 1$ and that $x\geq 0$. Since the derivative is a sum of non-negative real numbers, and the derivative will be positive (except perhaps at $x=0$). This means that our function is increasing.

Consider any two arbitrary $x_1,x_2$ such that $x_1<x_2$. We can integrate the derivative as follows:$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f'(x)~dx = f(x_2)-f(x_1)
$$We know that $f'(x) > 0$ as well as $x_2-x_1 > 0 \implies dx > 0$. Since the integral is just a sum of these terms, we can say that $f(x_2)-f(x_1) > 0 \implies f(x_2)>f(x_1)$. This gets us to our definition of increasing:$$
\forall x_1,x_2 \in [0,\infty)\quad x_1<x_2 \implies f(x_1) < f(x_2)
$$